# Finding AVERAGEIFS for just the 5 Highest Values in a Set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm trying to get the Average Price if these criteria are met...

1. Search Term = "cup"
2. Top Competitor = "TRUE"
3. I'd only like to average the Top 5 results (by Search Ranking) in the set.

So the formula should return 8.00

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,"cup",D:D,"TRUE",B:B,"<="&SMALL(B:B,5))

My formula is returning 7.5, which is too low. The formula seems to work until I add in the last criteria: B:B,"<="&SMALL(B:B,5)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Search Term | Rank | Price | Top Competitor |
| 2 | cup | 1 | 5.00 | TRUE |
| 3 | cup | 2 | 5.00 | FALSE |
| 4 | cup | 3 | 10.00 | TRUE |
| 5 | cup | 4 | 5.00 | TRUE |
| 6 | cup | 5 | 5.00 | FALSE |
| 7 | cup | 6 | 10.00 | FALSE |
| 8 | cup | 7 | 10.00 | TRUE |
| 9 | cup | 8 | 10.00 | TRUE |
| 10 | cup | 9 | 5.00 | TRUE |
| 11 | cup | 10 | 5.00 | TRUE |
| 12 | plate | 1 | 20.00 | TRUE |
| 13 | plate | 2 | 10.00 | FALSE |
| 14 | plate | 3 | 10.00 | TRUE |
| 15 | plate | 4 | 20.00 | TRUE |
| 16 | plate | 5 | 10.00 | FALSE |
| 17 | plate | 6 | 20.00 | FALSE |
| 18 | plate | 7 | 20.00 | FALSE |
| 19 | plate | 8 | 20.00 | FALSE |
| 20 | plate | 9 | 15.00 | TRUE |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you let us know the version of Excel?

Comment: Can you tell is what is the correct answer plz - 8 maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to apply the ranking parameter AFTER you have applied the cup and true parameters.

You did not indicate what you want to happen if there are not 5 items that meet your `Search Term` and `Top Competitor` requirements.  So both of these formulas will return an error for `plate` since you only have four (4) `TRUE`'s

In Excel Office 365, you can use:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(tbl,(tbl[Search Term]="cup")*tbl[Top Competitor]),AVERAGE(FILTER(INDEX(x,0,3),INDEX(x,0,2)<=SMALL(INDEX(x,0,2),5))))
```

where you first filter by cup and true; and then look at the top five of the filtered result.

If you have an earlier version, you can try this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(tbl[Price],tbl[Rank],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((tbl[Search Term]="cup")*tbl[Top Competitor])*tbl[Rank],{1;2;3;4;5}),tbl[Search Term],"cup",tbl[Top Competitor],TRUE))
```

Note that in both formulas, I used a Table with structured references. You can, of course, use regular references if you prefer.

The second formula will return an array of values, which are the one's to be averaged.

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: I like this direction but your first formula is returning #VALUE!. Does this look correct? =LET(x,FILTER(A:D,(A:A="cup")*D:D),AVERAGE(FILTER(INDEX(x,0,3),INDEX(x,0,2)<=SMALL(INDEX(x,0,2),5))))

Your second formula works for cup but for plate it gives me #DIV/0!. =AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(C:C,B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((A:A="plate")*D:D)*B:B,{1;2;3;4;5}),A:A,"cup",D:D,TRUE))

Thanks!

Comment: @phxdrupal Apparently with whole column references, you have to explicitly set the equality, so `=LET(x,FILTER(A:D,(A:A="cup")*(D:D=TRUE)),AVERAGE(FILTER(INDEX(x,0,3),INDEX(x,0,2)<=SMALL(INDEX(x,0,2),5))))`

Comment: @phxdrupal With regard to the errors with `"plate"`, please re-read the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @phxdrupal To be more specific, the reason for requiring explicitly setting the equality for column D, when you are using whole column references, is because your reference then includes the column header, which is text that does not evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Using a **Table** (or excluding the header row), avoids that difficulty.  Trying to multiply something by a string results in the `#VALUE!` error because the header string, being text, is of the `wrong data type` for the multiplication operation.